# Actionscript 3 Date adds 1 month

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi I'm having a problem setting a date in as3

here is the code i'm using

```
    var endDate = new Date(2009,9,10);
trace (endDate);
```

the trace statement always shows the date as 1 month further on the the date I have added eg

10th Oct 2009 instead of 10th september 2009

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3):

The month is 0 index.

```
var endDate = new Date(2009,9-1,10);
```

Comment: The same imbecile who wrote that class thought it would be swell to have days 1-based at the same time. For optimal confusion, the original design had an American date order (mm,dd,yyyy) in the constructor too.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, dates are zero indexed in AS, so you'll need to subtract one

Answer (score 0):

0 indexed like the other said. Try and take a look at this post for more tips on the date object:

[How can you save time by using the built in Date class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744057/how-can-you-save-time-by-using-the-built-in-date-class)

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are converting strings to numbers.
(Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type Number.)
If you just make it:

```
var day:Number=parseInt("10");
var month:Number=parseInt("9");
var year:Number=parseInt("2009");

var adjMonth =month-1;

var endDate = new Date(year,adjMonth,day);

trace(endDate.toString());
```

It'll work fine.