# Add days to Date in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

We have an application in which the user has to enter a date who's value is no more than 30 days after the the current date (the date on which the user uses the application). This is a Flash application, therefore I need a way to add 30 days to the current date, and get the right date. Something like in JavaScript:

```
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+30);
```

Or in C#:

```
DateTime.Now.Add(30);
```

Is there such a thing in ActionScript?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

While the other answers will work im sure, it is as easy as doing:

```
var dte:Date = new Date();
dte.date += 30; 
//the date property is the day of the month, so on Sept. 15 2009 it will be 15
```

This will even increment the month if necessary and year as well.  You can do this with the month and year properties as well.

Comment: That's great! I just want to emphasize that this works only in AS3

Comment: That is true.  Also remember that the month property is 0 based.  So January is month 0 and December is month 11.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you look here: [How can you save time by using the built in Date class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744057/how-can-you-save-time-by-using-the-built-in-date-class/744068#744068).

It should be something like this:

```
var date:Date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.date + 30);
```

Comment: date.date - Properties are case sensitive.

Comment: Correct, I have updated the code.
I never liked the actionscript naming convention ;)

Answer (score 3):

My [TimeSpan class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169201/actionscript-3-0-calculate-timespan-between-two-dates) might prove useful here (it's a port of the .NET System.TimeSpan):

```
var now : Date = new Date();
var threeDaysTime : Date = TimeSpan.fromDays(3).add(now);
```

Comment: Thanks, other examples just added days but didn't increase the month.

Answer (score 2):

@Zerata

Adding milliseconds directly will not work if dates are across day light saving change...

However, you can add seconds directly:

> var date: Date = new Date();
>   date.seconds += 86400;
>   => this works even if dates are across DLS change.

Maurice

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing the code from the top of my head, without compiling it, but I'd use getTime(). Something like:

```
var today : Date = new Date();
var futureDate : Date = new Date();
futureDate.setTime(today.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
```

1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 = milliseconds * seconds * minutes * hours * days

Makes sense?