# flash cs4 countdown clock

Tags: actionscript-3

hi there I have a flash cs4 countdown clock but I want to play a sound when timer reaches hours 0, minutes 0, seconds 0. e.g. New Years Day as target time any ideas?

p.s this is using actionscript 3

Answer (score 1):

var delay:uint = calculate time that is left to newyear in milliseconds
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(delay, 1);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, newYearCallback);

```
function newYearCallback(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    playYourSound();
}
```

Comment: After the addEventListener line don't forget to call timer.start() or the countdown will never begin ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have built a couple of different timer applications in Flash and I must tell you that Flash's timing isn't perfect... I have always encountered drift even over as short a time span as several minutes.

But if you do feel so compelled... Check the responses here:
[Add days to Date in ActionScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425677/add-days-to-date-in-actionscript)

And to play the sound, try something like:

```
var sound:Sound = new Sound();
sound.attachSound("mySound");
sound.start(0,0);
```